# Self-adjoint operator on the space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, adjoint-operators

The vector space $ \mathbb{R} [X]_p$ of real-valued polynomial of rank $< p$ 
is provided with the scalar product
$$ \langle f,g\rangle  := \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) dx.$$

To Show is that the linear Transformation  $L: \mathbb{R} [X]_p \to \mathbb{R} [X]_p, f \to [(1-X^2)f']' $ is self-adjoint regarding $\langle ,\rangle $, and also determine the Eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I know how to Show self-adjointed matrices..but i have no idea how to do this Task. Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

The adjoint of a function $f$ is the function $g$ such that for all vectors $x, y$:

$$ \langle x, f(y) \rangle = \langle g(x), y \rangle.$$
Thus, you must show that for all polynomials $f, g \in \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq p}$:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 f(x) [(1-x^2)g'(x)]'dx=\int_{-1}^1 [(1-x^2)f'(x)]'g(x)dx.$$
Alternatively, you could transform the question into one of matrices, calculating the matrix for the map $L$ after choosing a basis for $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq p}$.

Comment: alright, thank you so far.

Comment: i just have some issues with coming from one side to the other:  $ \int_{-1}^1 f(x)[(1-x^2)g'(x)]' dx = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)(-2x*g'(x)+(1-x^2)*g''(x) dx = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)(-2x)g'(x) dx+ \int_{-1}^1 f(x)(1-x^2)g''(x) dx $. Is this the right way?

Comment: @wondering1123 You'll have to use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of degree at most $p$, for this is not true in general.

Comment: I have no idea how to use that.... cant be p any Number ? I am sorry, i just Try to prepare for maths at University. So im am still a noob 

Comment: Solved !:)  thank you ! but how can i determine the Eigenvalues?